# Minikube MountVolume failed for volume "config-volume"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm facing an issue with my ubuntu:16.04 desktop, using minikube version: v0.35.0, kubectl both client/server: 1.13.4

When I try running a configmap example and get error kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed every time I try. I tried to debug but no result on my end. It's about last 2 days and failed to make it work.

$ kubectl apply -f ./kube-pod.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kuard-config
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:1
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
        - "/kuard"
        - "$(EXTRA_PARAM)"
      env:
        - name: ANOTHER_PARAM
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: my-config
              key: another-param
        - name: EXTRA_PARAM
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: my-config
              key: extra-param
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: "/config"
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: my-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Giving the following error when I run the following command

$ kubectl describe pods/kuard-config

````
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Thu, 20 Jun 2019 10:44:37 +0600
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"ann
otations":{},"name":"kuard-config","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"containers":[{"command"...
Status:             Pending
IP:
Containers:
  test-container:
    Container ID:
    Image:         gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:1
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /kuard
      $(EXTRA_PARAM)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      ANOTHER_PARAM:  <set to the key 'another-param' of config map 'my-config'>  Optional: false
      EXTRA_PARAM:    <set to the key 'extra-param' of config map 'my-config'>    Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /config from config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-q42jl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      my-config
    Optional:  false
  default-token-q42jl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-q42jl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age               From               Message
  ----     ------       ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    12s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kuard-config to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  4s (x5 over 11s)  kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" : configmap "my-config" not found```

I'd expect if someone help me to figure out why `kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed` is occur.
````

Comment: could you please run `kubectl get cm my-config -o yaml` you should have ConfigMap: my-config but as we can see  `configmap "my-config" not found`.

Comment: Any update on this [gmaam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10000006/gmaam) ?